# how to create insert query on the fly, in entity framework using create query method?

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I am using something like the above sample code but when i try to execute it, it says that 
the query syntax is wrong and there is an error in the query syntax near keyword into...

```
System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter[] opc=new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter[1];  //sample
opc[0]=new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("columnname","columnvaluetoinsert")
string strQuery="insert into tablename(columnname)values(@columnname)";
var query1 = entities.CreateQuery<System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject>(strQuery, opc);
query1.Execute(System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking);
```

Comment: There is most likely a better way of performing your insert then creating a query 'on the fly'.  Can you provide more details about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Actually I have to create a common method through I can insert the data in some tables which  have similar column names and numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now after more than four months or so I can answer this...

```
string tableName = "yourTableName";
string PrimaryColName = "PrimarykeyName";

using(Entities entities = new Entities) 
{ 
  string sQuery= " select value " + tableName + " from " + tableName + " as " + tableName; 
 sQuery += " where ";
 sQuery += tableName + ".PrimaryColName " = " + lngMasterId;

 System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery query = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery(sMasterTableName, entities); 
 //where entities is the object of your objectContext class :) 
 return query.First();//do whatever you want with the result 
}
```

here `"value"` after the `"select"` tells to give the result in the custom anonymous format